# How to sum only few rows of table and the result compare with another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to sum few rows of table, depending on information from antoher table.
Example:

```
SELECT ARRIVALS.FLIGHT_NUMBER, 
       SUM(RESERVATIONS.TICKET_COUNT) FROM 
ARRIVALS JOIN 
  RESERVATIONS ON (ARRIVALS.FLIGHT_NUMBER=RESERVATIONS.FLIGHT_NUMBER)
```

I need to see flight number, with sum of reservated tickets to this flight. Like there are 2-3 reservations on each flight.

Than I have to compare that sum of reservated tickets to count of avaiable tickets. There is a code (with part of right solution from this thread):

```
SELECT ARRIVALS.FLIGHT_NUMBER FROM ARRIVALS 
WHERE (SELECT SUM(R.TICKET_COUNT) AS TICKETS 
       FROM ARRIVALS A JOIN RESERVATIONS R ON A.FLIGHT_NUMBER = R.FLIGHT_NUMBER 
       GROUP BY A.FLIGHT_NUMBER) = (SELECT TICKETS.TICKET_COUNT FROM TICKETS 
                                    JOIN RESERVATIONS ON TICKETS.FLIGHT_NUMBER = RESERVATIONS.FLIGHT_NUMBER);
```

RESERVATIONS are like:

```
ID,FLIGHT_NUMBER,TICKET_COUNT,CUSTOMER_ID
```

TICKETS are like:

```
ID,FLIGHT_NUMBER,TICKET_COUNT
```

and ARRIVALS are like:

```
ID,FLIGHT_NUMBER,CAPACITY
```

I have to select only that flights, which are completely sold out.

Comment: What do you mean by summing only few rows of table? Please present sample data, expected result and RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is missing a `GROUP BY` clause in your query. Other than that it seems right.

```
SELECT A.FLIGHT_NUMBER, SUM(R.TICKET_COUNT) AS TICKETS
FROM ARRIVALS A
JOIN RESERVATIONS R ON A.FLIGHT_NUMBER = R.FLIGHT_NUMBER
GROUP BY A.FLIGHT_NUMBER
```

You can read about `GROUP BY` statement [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

> The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

**Edit after your edit**

To get flight numbers that are sold out (have all reserved tickets) assuming that in `TICKETS` you only hold one row for each `flight_number` here's the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT A.FLIGHT_NUMBER, sum(R.TICKET_COUNT) AS RESERVED_TICKETS
  FROM ARRIVALS A
  JOIN RESERVATIONS R ON A.FLIGHT_NUMBER = R.FLIGHT_NUMBER
  GROUP BY A.FLIGHT_NUMBER
  ) FOO
JOIN TICKETS T ON FOO.FLIGHT_NUMBER = T.FLIGHT_NUMBER
WHERE FOO.RESERVED_TICKETS = T.TICKET_COUNT
```

Here's <kbd>[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ee5a/12)</kbd> to present you sample result.

If you have more rows for each `flight_number` in table `TICKETS` then you need a `GROUP BY` statement and `HAVING`.

Comment: Yeah, that's great. Do you think you could help me a little more?
I have to compare that sum of reservated tickets to count of avaiable tickets.
There is a code:

`
SELECT ARRIVALS.FLIGHT_NUMBER
FROM ARRIVALS
WHERE (SELECT SUM(R.TICKET_COUNT) AS TICKETS
FROM ARRIVALS A
JOIN RESERVATIONS R ON A.FLIGHT_NUMBER = R.FLIGHT_NUMBER
GROUP BY A.FLIGHT_NUMBER)
       =
       (SELECT TICKETS.TICKET_COUNT FROM TICKETS
       JOIN RESERVATIONS ON TICKETS.FLIGHT_NUMBER = RESERVATIONS.FLIGHT_NUMBER);    
`

I have to select only that flights, which are completely sold out.
THANK YOU!

Comment: It's hard to tell since I don't know what issues you are facing. Please post another question should you have some more problems you're dealing with.

Comment: haha, I accidentaly sent that without details:) code in another answer here, thanks!

Comment: You should __not__ post your question as an answer. Create a new question with a different problem, instead.

Comment: well I have to wait for 90 minutes or something.. but I must hand in that code till midnight..:/

Comment: Do as I said in my comment to your question. Post your table definitions and sample data (by __editing__ your question), add your problem and approach and I __may__ be able to help you out.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Why did you unaccept it? It was originally accepted by you and it was my choice to assistance you in further problems. That was just rude.

Comment: sorry, I though it would look like solved thread, I've accepted it again, thank you!